# How to group multiple colums like a single block with outer border

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am working on *NetBeans IDE 7.2* with *iReport* plugin. Any how I managed to generate report but now I trying to group some columns to display like a blocks.

Here is screenshot what I have:

[image]

I am trying to do this:

[image]

I am new with *iReport*. Please suggest me some to accomplish this.

Comment: You can set borders for *textFields*

Comment: I am not using text field, Its a iReport table

Comment: Can you post the jrxml file?

Comment: why negative ? please give solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add vertical line after the specific column by adding the bellow code in XML

```
<line>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1" height="30"/>
</line>
```

By using this vertical line your problem may solved.